# When the Json structure changes, i get io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input

Tags: json

I implemented Ktor in my project, I used to constantly use Retrofit 2. And now I can’t get around the error that occurs very often due to the fact that now the server part is in the development of a new API. Any change there leads, to failure for me.

I keep getting error `with exception: io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: invalid input`
And I need time to find the reason.

```
@Serializable
data class FileUploadResponse(
    @SerialName("data")
    val `data`: FileUploadResponseData? = null,
    @SerialName("message")
    val message: String? = null,
    @SerialName("status")
    val status: String? = null
)

@Serializable
data class FileUploadResponseData(
    @SerialName("path")
    val path: String,
    @SerialName("original_name") // this error
    val originalName: String
)
```

Json

```
{
"status": "success",
   "data": {
       "path": "temp/dfec6bca2a5d13eb0a2bc319900c46d5.pdf",
       "originalName": "93c076d0-563e-4abd-8b4e-1448ad83561d.pdf"
    }
}
```

Right now I managed to get an exception: `io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Invalid input`. To fix this I need to change `@SerialName("original_name")` to @SerialName("**originalName**").

**But this is one way to make this mistake ((**

Koltin.kt

```
@Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideClient(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
        protoApi: ProtoApi,
    ): HttpClient {
        return HttpClient(Android) {
            /*defaultRequest {
                url(HttpRoutes.BASE_URL)
            }*/
            install(Logging) {
                level = LogLevel.ALL
            }
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json(Json {
                    prettyPrint = true
                    isLenient = false
                    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                    explicitNulls = false
                })
            }
            install(Auth) {
                bearer {
                    //...
                }
            }
        }
```

```
// ktor_version = '2.3.0'
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:2.3.0"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:$ktor_version"
implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.0'
```

I read the official documentation but didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

I have updated ktor to version **2.3.2**. And now I have a more clear error message.

Now in the console I see an error.

```
https://api.domen.staj.bid/api/v1/projects/add-client failed with exception: io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input: Field 'errors' is required for type with serial name 'com.domen.ktor.clients.projects_add_client.ProjectsAddClientResponse', but it was missing at path: $
```

Where 'errors' is the error